# Getting error with when condition in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this

```
dry_run: "{{ lookup('env','DRY_RUN') | default(yes,true) }}"
```

and i get this error

i am using like

```
when: dry_run
```

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The
>   conditional check 'dry_run' failed. The error was: error while
>   evaluating conditional (dry_run): 'yes' is undefined\n\nThe error
>   appears to have been in

i even tried

`when: dry_run | bool` as well

> The error was: error while evaluating conditional (dry_run|bool): {{
>   lookup('env','DRY_RUN') | default(yes,true) }}: 'yes' is
>   undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in

Comment: What is `dry_run`? A fact or variable?

Comment: @techraf   its variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `default(true)` instead of `default(yes)` (it is a Jinja2 template, not YAML, so `yes` is not synonymous with `true`) and set a fact so what you don't use template in a conditional:

```
- set_fact:
    dry_run: "{{ lookup('env','DRY_RUN') | default(true, true) }}"

- debug:
  when: dry_run
```

Comment: why i need to set as fact , why cant i use variables.

Comment: I wrote it in the answer. Ansible will complain because your variable contains a template.

Comment: but i have 15 more variables , which i use like that. i have used them all over the place

Comment: example i used `rtype: "{{ lookup('env','RTYPE') | default('C12',true) }}"`and in playbook i use `when: rtype[:2] in ['C1']` . this worked fine without any issue
`

Comment: i think that work because i have the env variable , the problem only happens when env is absent

Comment: What is your problem now? Ansible issues a warning in such a case. Are you trying to convince me I should amend my answer, because you ignore warnings?

Comment: i didn't understood what u mean . can you show me what warning you are talking about. i will see if get that in my playbook bceause i have been using that for more than month and it was working for me. its only today that dry run is not working

Comment: " [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters
such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: ..."

Comment: i checked and i never got that warning. that rtype example i gave you is working without any issue for long time. what u say , it should not  have worked?

Comment: Finally found the issue, we both are right. It works fine with vars as well . i was using the `when`  on include of playbook , which didn't had that variable file included. so i had to use set_fact becuause fact survives across playbook. it could also work if i include that var file , thne i dont need to use set fact. thanks problem solved now